# Which is the most memory intensive SQL query: select, update or insert?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

Which is the most memory intensive SQL query: select, update or insert? and why?

The database consists of a two simple tables that are independent of each other

Comment: Depends on the query? `SELECT "Constant"` is not as intensive as `INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM largetable, anotherlargetable` ;)

Comment: Which is the most calorie-intensive mode of self-propulsion: running or bicycling? And why?

Comment: Matt, I was thinking about similar type question but related to comparing arms, stomach and head... LOL

Comment: Too hypothetical to really be answered without specific information about the context.

Comment: You seem to have a very simplistic view of how computers use memory and how Oracle in particular uses it.  Oracle has very documentation, which is available online.  In this case you need to read the Concepts Guide, which devotes an entire chapter to Oracle's Memory Architecture: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/memory.htm#i12483   Read it, and then ask us some specific questions.

Comment: @Matt Ball - your analogy is flawed: SQL statements don't *consume* memory, they fill it and then free it.  A better question might have been: which takes up the most shelf space, a set of encyclopedias or month's worth of periodicals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on what is being requested in the query and the size of each table. A select all

```
SELECT * FROM Table
```

will consume whatever memory required to load records in that table.

Comment: Incorrect. The entire result set isn't stored in memory, merely a part of it.

Comment: True, I edited my comment to make this clearer. I meant to imply that some records are larger than others, such as those with BLOBs stored in them.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say anything without knowing the actual statements but selects, especially joins and resultsets with many records are probably use more memory